# List the items having tags <li><ui> of the XML file using xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

i have my XML like this

```
<p>
    <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
        <li>shilk</li>
        <li>tilk</li>
        <li>pilk</li>
    </ul>
</p>
```

and i m converting this tags into this format using XSLT

```
<ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>shilk</li>
    <li>tilk</li>
    <li>pilk</li>
</ul>
```

but i didnt find any api or method to do this i tried but how to show that symbol and list the items correctly in a order.
and i m using this code to perform this but its not wrking

```
<xsl:template match="p">        
        <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="ul">    
          <li><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></li>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: are you sure, you posted the right code? What you posted is simple html. The 'symbol' can be changed using css. An there's no different in the order of your "xml" and ""transformed" output.

Comment: @JohannesStaehlin yes actually i m using this html code as a XML and pls check the edited code i added <p> as a root element

Comment: I still don't get it. if I copy your file in an html code, it is displayed like the list in your post. So WHAT are you actually converting? ("this tags into this format")?

Comment: copy this html code in the XML file and then using XSLT i want to show that code in HTML fromat , exactly as u see when u copy ur code in the HTML.is problem clear to you @JohannesStaehlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your output is HTML: below is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="p">
      <xsl:for-each select="ul">
        <ul>
          <xsl:for-each select="li">
            <li>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </li>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

- Coffee
- Milk
- shilk
- tilk
- pilk

Comment: @Aravin my code is not working and the line u provide me is just give me the symbol what about the text...??

Comment: @Librak, figured out the problem :) I will edit it please check then.

Comment: @Librak, you were missing a `<xsl:for-each/>` loop, Also observe that I have set `output method="html"` :) If your output method="xml", then output will be simple XML, so you don't see bullets ..

Comment: Please remember that some people will start reading your question from the top. Only when they get to the end of the thread will they realize that you have edited your question to replace your incorrect code with correct code. So you're wasting a lot of their time. Don't do it!

Comment: What do you mean when you say *If your output method="xml", then output will be simple XML, so you don't see bullets*? You can use method="xml" and still output html that will display bullets in the browser.

Comment: @DevNull, agreed .. but usually XSLT editors (ex: MS-VS) show ouput in accordance with output property .. As OP is a rookie, I explained him in his ways .. Also I guessed he wants to learn usage of `For-each` so I didn't post alternative solutions but edited his own post :)

Comment: editors parse XML, where as I think .. browsers render XML (probably with XSLT) .. I have observed keenly that browsers collapse white-space, if am correct, its HTML behavior. So it applies html nodes and escape-characters as well .. so bullets find their original form.. thats why the difference in behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really necessary to use so many `xsl:for-each` to do this transform. What you should really do is use an [identity template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and override it for the `<p>` element. That way if you need to make additional changes to other parts of your XML, it's much easier to modify your stylesheet by overriding the identity template.

Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity template. This will copy everything unchanged. (unless it's 
       matched by another template)-->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using your input, it will output the following:

```
<ul>
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
   <li>shilk</li>
   <li>tilk</li>
   <li>pilk</li>
</ul>
```

Which looks like this in a browser:

- Coffee
- Milk
- shilk
- tilk
- pilk

Answer (score 0):

**I. This is probably the simplest and shortest solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<p>
    <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
        <li>shilk</li>
        <li>tilk</li>
        <li>pilk</li>
    </ul>
</p>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<ul>
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
   <li>shilk</li>
   <li>tilk</li>
   <li>pilk</li>
</ul>
```

---

**II. A more extensible solution -- overriding the identity rule**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```